# No crash reports from Crashlytics on iOS 11 / Xcode 9

Tags: ios, ios11, crashlytics, xcode9, google-fabric

Crashlytics/Fabric crash reporting solution worked flawlessly for years, but after upgrade to `Xcode 9` or `iOS 11` I don't see crash reports from my debug builds anymore. I attached `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()` to a button, running the app with cable unplugged as I did dozens of times before, app crashes but I don't see crash reports on the website. What could be the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unplugging a cable from the device used to be a sure way to detach an app from the debugger. But with the introduction of **wireless debugging** in `Xcode 9` it's no longer the case. You have to disable network debugging by opening Devices screen (Shift+Cmd+2) and unchecking **Connect via network** to *really* detach your device from the debugger.